# New column by Slicing string from another column on transpose of a dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice a substring from a column and get it in another column. I have read multiple links but this problem exists because my dataframe that I will be working on is Transpose. (This is a minimum reproducible example, the original dataframe is huge and I have to work with the transposed data only).

**df**(How to generate df for this question, sample df,minimum reproducible eg.)

```
[IN]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': ['BIKES','MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'],
                   'JAN15 SVAL': [1,3,6,10],
                   'FEB15 SVAL': [4,5, 6,16],
                'MAR15 SVAL':[13, 14,10,12]})
dft1 = df.set_index('SKU').T
```

Other info:

```
[IN]dft1.columns
[OUT]Index(['BIKES', 'MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'], dtype='object', name='SKU')
[IN]print(dft1.index.name)
[OUT]None
```

**Expected output for dft1:**

```
     SKU         BIKES  MATS  BLANKETS  CREAMS  month  year month_number  Date
JAN15 SVAL      1     3         6      10        JAN   2015   1           2015-01-01
FEB15 SVAL      4     5         6      16        FEB   2015   2           2015-02-01
MAR15 SVAL     13    14        10      12        MAR   2015   3           2015-03-01
```

**Code tried so far** which does not work and gives error as mentioned in [OUT]

```
[IN]dft1['month'] = dft1['SKU'].apply(lambda x: x[:3])
[IN]dft1['year']=2000 + dft1['SKU'].str[3:5].astype(int)
[IN]cmap = {'JAN': 1, 'FEB': 2, 'MAR': 3, 'APR': 4, 'MAY': 5, 'JUN': 6,'JUL':7, 'AUG':8,'SEP':9,'OCT':10,'NOV':11,'DEC':12}
[IN]dft1['Month Number']=dft1['month'].map(cmap)
[IN]dft1['Month Number']=dft1['Month Number'].round(0)
[IN]dft1['Date']=(pd.to_datetime(dft1['year'].astype(str)  + dft1['month'], format='%Y%b'))

[OUT]KeyError: 'SKU'
```

P.S. **I dont want to set the first column SKU as index** **to slice** the data as there are other dataframes(transposed ones where the column from which data needs to be sliced from strings are not in the first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `SKU` as index, if so then reset index and rename column, else proceed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': ['BIKES','MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'],
                   'JAN15 SVAL': [1,3,6,10],
                   'FEB15 SVAL': [4,5, 6,16],
                'MAR15 SVAL':[13, 14,10,12]})
dft1 = df.set_index('SKU').T

if dft1.columns.name == 'SKU':
    dft1 = dft1.reset_index()
    dft1.rename(columns={'index':'SKU'}, inplace=True)

cmap = {'JAN': 1, 'FEB': 2, 'MAR': 3, 'APR': 4, 'MAY': 5, 'JUN': 6,'JUL':7, 'AUG':8,'SEP':9,'OCT':10,'NOV':11,'DEC':12}
dft1['month'] = dft1.index.str[0:3]
dft1['year'] = 2000 + (dft1.index.astype(str).str[3:5]).astype(int)
dft1['Month Number'] = dft1['month'].map(cmap)
dft1['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(dft1['year'].astype(str)  + dft1['month'], format='%Y%b'))
```

Output:

```
SKU         BIKES  MATS  BLANKETS  CREAMS month  year  Month Number       Date
JAN15 SVAL      1     3         6      10   JAN  2015             1 2015-01-01
FEB15 SVAL      4     5         6      16   FEB  2015             2 2015-02-01
MAR15 SVAL     13    14        10      12   MAR  2015             3 2015-03-01
```

Comment: Like I said I dont want dft1.index.str....I dont want to use SKU column as index as there are other dataframes where SKU column wont be the first position column

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what did you mean by "I dont want to set the first column SKU as index to slice", but here is my solution.

```
dft1['dateField'] = dft1.index
dft1['month'] = dft1['dateField'].map(lambda x : x[:3])
dft1['year'] = dft1['dateField'].map(lambda x : '20' + x[3:5])
dft1['Date'] = dft1.apply(lambda x : str(x['year']) + '-' + str(x['month']) + '-0' +  str(1), axis = 1)
dft1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dft1['Date'], format = '%Y-%b-%d')
del dft1['dateField']
```

for month number the mapping you have should be used.